# send data to PHP from iphone app in objective c

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xml-parsing

i have an app which needs to send data to mysql to insert into my tables. So I am using PHP to achieve this. But the problem is that I am not able to send data with spaces in between. How can I achieve this? Do I need to encode the data in xml/JSON or is there any other way? If I need to encode the data..how should I do it?

Any help is appreciated.

PHP code:

```
$guesttype = $_GET["guesttype"];
$guestLname =$_GET["guestLname"];
$guestFname =$_GET["guestFname"];

----
echo "something";
```

OBJECTIVE C CODE:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:PHPurlwithargs ,userName, password, hostName, DBName, function, userCompany, _todisplaytype];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Make sure your requests are properly URI encoded, where space shows up as `%20`. For debugging you might want to use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/) to examine your network calls. If you're new to PHP, don't try building this sort of thing from the ground up, it's very tricky and error-prone. It's much better to familiarize yourself with a [popular PHP framework](http://crunchify.com/the-5-most-relevant-php-frameworks-in-2013/) and make use of the foundation those give you for writing apps like this.

Comment: use JSON to encode in objective c and in php `json_decode($data)`

Comment: @dianuj can you tell me how I can encode data using json in objective C

Answer (score 1):

JSON encode your data in objective-c before sending it over to your PHP block. That should take care of any spaces that may be passed along as well.

ie. NSString* stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Does this NSString* stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; encode the data in JSON?? Sorry, it may be a silly question..but i am new here :( If not can you tell me how I can encode in JSON..Thanks!!