# Send Textfield value into PHP MySQL using xcode 8 (Objective-c) with or without click action?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode8

I just want to ask on how to **send textfield value into mysql database** in xcode using obj c **without any click action** or **with click action**?

If the code below can retrieve and display JSON data from web server into xcode:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize username,email;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *url_string    = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost/test.php"];
    NSData *data            = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
    NSMutableArray *json    = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary *dict      = [json firstObject];
    NSString *data1         = [dict valueForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *data2         = [dict valueForKey:@"email"];
    email.text              = data1;
    pw.text                 = data2;   
}
@end
```

How to **post username, email** value into mysql database? Is it the same technique applied on post method? Because I do not want to use SBJson classes (if possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send data to PHP from iphone app in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004566/send-data-to-php-from-iphone-app-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. First, it is important to notice that `dataWithContentsOfURL` is not an asynchronous request. Meaning that if you use it to transfer large data, there is a good chance that you will freeze the app. For async requests, you should use the NSURLRequest.

Having said that, there are excellent API to upload/download data asynchronously. One which is very frequently used, and well documented is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). This is coded on top of NSURLRequest.

For example, in your PHP you can retrieve the fields from a POST statement like this:

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
?>
```

In your app, you can call the PHP script with a POST request in AFNetworking as follow:

```
NSString *username = @"username";
NSString *email = @"email";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"yourUrl" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSLog(@"Sending POST request to server");

    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"username"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"email"];

} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"SERVER UPLOAD FRACTION COMPLETED: %f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
    });

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject %@", responseObject);
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"The respose is: %@", responseString);

    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"The response is: %@", responseString);
        // Do something with the response
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex . I'll try your suggestion :)

Comment: Hi, i managed to post the data using the other code in this link. Can you help me to solve this question on this link ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560364/how-to-pass-textfield-value-as-string-type-in-x-code-8-swift-3.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSDictionary *jsondata = @{
                           @"username":email.text,
                           @"password":pw.text  

                          };


                NSString *requestString = [jsondata jsonStringWithPrettyPrint:YES];

                NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:YOUR_URL_HERE];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8 " forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                //Handle your response here
            }];
            [task resume];
```